# How to read json data from AngularJs (front end) to Grails (server side) through $http

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails

I have to send a json data  from Angular to Grails through $http service method. The JSON data has been sent to the server. But in server side it doesn't print the param values. I'm new to Grails.

**My Code:**

Controller:

```
$(function(){

    gateApp.factory('saveCreateToServer', function($http){
        return {
            saveDataToServer:function(taskCreateFormData){
                console.log(taskCreateFormData);

                return $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'save',
                    data    :  taskCreateFormData, 
                })
            }
         }
    });

    gateApp.controller('moveTaskRuleDefCtrl', function($scope, saveCreateToServer){
        $scope.saveCreate=function() {
            var reqData = angular.toJson($scope.taskCreateForm);
            saveCreateToServer.saveDataToServer(reqData).success(function(data) {
            });
        }
    });
})
```

In Server Side:

```
 def save(params){
        println "<<<<<<<<<uu<<<<<<<<<"+params
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post data using `$http` with `data` key, the data is not sent as query or form data instead it sent using body parameters. So you can not read it with `params`, just use `request.JSON`:

```
def save() {
    Map requestData = request.JSON
    println "Data: " + requestData
    println "Data: " + requestData.firstName
}
```

Also, you don't have to convert the object to JSON string, you can just pass the data:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/save",
    data: {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
});
```

**Update on passing data as form data**

Yes, you can absolutely do it so that you don't have to change the server side code. So basically, Angular by default sends data with `Content-Type` as `application/json` so the Grails receives it as `request.JSON`. So just change it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/save",
    data: {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"},
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

Now, the params will be available as `params` in the Grails controller.

Comment: fine. actually i am working in migrate to angular js.. so now i can't able to change server side code..so how can i change and send json data favor to params receive method..i want to receive json data by using params..so what can i do for that..

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer including fix for your problem.